# WPF DataContext is set before properties that affect representation of DataContext are set

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` that represents my custom `DataContext` to the user. This control also has a `DependencyProperty` (with a `PropertyChangedCallback`) that affects the way the `DataContext` is shown to the user.

My custom `UserControl` XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="Me">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FinalText,ElementName=Me}"/>
</UserControl>
```

My custom `UserControl` code behind:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MyControl
    {
        #region Static Fields and Constants
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CapitalizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Capitalize), typeof(bool),
            typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), CapitalizePropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FinalTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(FinalText), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion

        #region Properties and Indexers
        public bool Capitalize
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(CapitalizeProperty);
            set => SetValue(CapitalizeProperty, value);
        }

        public string FinalText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(FinalTextProperty);
            set
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Setting {nameof(FinalText)} to value {value}");
                SetValue(FinalTextProperty, value);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private members
        private static void CapitalizePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (d is MyControl me)
                me.CreateFinalText(me.DataContext as string);
        }

        private void CreateFinalText(string text)
        {
            if (text != null)
            {
                FinalText = Capitalize ? text.ToUpperInvariant() : text.ToLowerInvariant();
            }
            else
            {
                FinalText = null;
            }
        }

        private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            CreateFinalText(args.NewValue as string);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

When I use my `UserControl` in the following way:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyControl DataContext="Simple string" Capitalize="True"/>
</Grid>
```

My debug output shows the following:

> Setting FinalText to value simple string
>   Setting FinalText to value SIMPLE STRING

**I was wondering if it's possible to have the `DependencyProperty` `Capitalize` set before the `DataContext` is set? That way the `FinalText` property isn't set twice.**

To complicate my issue a bit further, my actual `UserControl` needs to support rendering to an `Image` without being attached to a `Window`, meaning the `Loaded` event doesn't always trigger.

I could add a `DependencyProperty` that is being used instead of the `DataContext`, but then there's still no way to ensure that this new `DependencyProperty` is filled after all my other `DependencyProperties` are filled (`Capitalize` in the example)

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comments, using the `DataContext` isn't recommended, and I should instead use another `Property` to set what needs to be rendered. That's fine and easy to do, however it still isn't guaranteed that this new `Property` is parsed after **all** the other `Properties` are parsed.
I guess the question could be reformulated to: **How to detect if a UserControl has been fully parsed from XAML?**

Comment: IMO using the DataContext like this is a bad idea in the first place. DataContext is meant to provide a default source object for Bindings on the dependency properties of your control. Your UserControl should simply have a Text property, which you may then bind like `Text="{Binding}"`. If you'd put the capitalization into a Binding Converter, you wouldn't even need the UserControl at all.

Comment: I can make a Text property, but that still doesn't guarantee that all other properties are filled already (which causes text to be LowerCase first and then set to UpperCase immediately after). As for capitalizing letters, it's just an example whereas my real usecase is more CPU-intensive. I guess the question could be reformulated to "How can I know the UserControl is fully parsed from XAML?"

Comment: The usual approach is to react on *every* property change and update the UI. Thus you'll always also get the "last" property change. If you want to do this lazily, use the Loaded event.

Comment: The Loaded event isn't triggered when the UserControl is loaded, it's triggered when the UserControl is attached to a VisualTree, which doesn't always happen (for example when rendering it in a RenderTargetBitmap)

Comment: I'd say *How to detect if a UserControl has been fully parsed from XAML?* is the wrong question. Even after having been "fully parsed", property changes may occur, e.g. through Bindings.

Comment: It makes sense to react to every property change, but it makes no sense to me to start doing that before it's been fully parsed to begin with.

Comment: When the visual appearance of a control should change due to a change of one or more of its dependency properties, you may consider overriding OnRender and register the dependency properties with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to have the DependencyProperty `Capitalize` set before the `DataContext` is set?

Try to change the order, i.e. set the `Capitalize` property before you set the `DataContext` property:

```
<local:MyControl Capitalize="True" DataContext="Simple string" />
```

Comment: There is no guarantee at all that this influences the order

Comment: That works, but I can't guarantee that everybody that uses my `UserControl` knows about it, it also means that `DataContext` has to be set explicitly. `<Grid DataContext="Amazing string"> <local:MyControl Capitalize="True" /> </Grid>` would cause the same issue.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: It will given the current implementation of the XAML parser.

Comment: @ManlkWeet: I just answered your question. If your internal implementation relies on the order, you should probably re-think your entire approach to whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: It doesn't 'depend' on it as much as it is an optimization. It is wasteful to generate FinalText and then immediately regenerate it before the control was even fully parsed.

Comment: Well, the only way to control the order in which properties are set is to set them in this order. This is true for both XAML and C#.

Comment: I would not want to base a solution on "the current implementation".

Comment: What else would you base it on? How the XAML parser behaves and works won't change anytime soon. Probably never. And how would to do this in c# if you can't assume that the code lines where you set the properties are executed one after another in the order you write them...?